# I want add new training phrases by don't delete old training phrases in intents

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

```
    intentRequest := &dialogflowpb.GetIntentRequest{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/agent/intents/%s", projectID, intentID),
    }

    // Retrieve the current intent
    intent, err := client.GetIntent(ctx, intentRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to get intent: %v", err)
    }

    // Create new training phrases with the new user expressions
    newTrainingPhrases := []*dialogflowpb.Intent_TrainingPhrase{
        {
            Parts: []*dialogflowpb.Intent_TrainingPhrase_Part{
                {
                    Text: inputmessage,
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // Append the new training phrases to the existing training phrases
    intent.TrainingPhrases = append(intent.TrainingPhrases, newTrainingPhrases...)

    // Create the intent update request
    updateRequest := &dialogflowpb.UpdateIntentRequest{
        //LanguageCode: "en",
        Intent: intent,
    }

    // Update the intent
    _, err = client.UpdateIntent(ctx, updateRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to update intent: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

#I want add new training phrases  by don't delete old training phrases in intents.
#Code me is add new training phrase but old training phrase disappear`w